# Enable and disable navigation Buttons for a ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I've got the following buttons to help navigate in a browser view:

```
<Button ToolTip="{StaticResource Back}" x:Name="BtnBack" Style="{StaticResource FaButton}" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None" Click="BtnBack_Click">
    <fa:FontAwesome Style="{StaticResource FaIcon}" Name="FaBack" Icon="ArrowLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Button>
<Button ToolTip="{StaticResource Forward}" x:Name="BtnForward" Style="{StaticResource FaButton}" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None" Click="BtnForward_Click">
    <fa:FontAwesome Style="{StaticResource FaIcon}" Name="FaForward" Icon="ArrowRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Button>
<Button ToolTip="{StaticResource BackToMenu}" x:Name="BtnHome" Style="{StaticResource FaButton}" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None" Click="BtnHome_Click">
    <fa:FontAwesome Style="{StaticResource FaIcon}" Icon="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Button>
```

I want to change the color of the buttons `BtnBack/FaBack` and `BtnForward/FaForward` depending on wether navigating forward/backward is possible. Therefore I use the following method which is bound to the `LoadingStateChangedEvent`:

```
private void CwbBrowser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args) {
    if (!args.IsLoading) {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate {
            if (!CwbBrowser.CanGoBack) {
                FaBack.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 25, 25, 25));
            } else {
                FaBack.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 68, 68));
            }
            if (!CwbBrowser.CanGoForward) {
                FaForward.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 25, 25, 25));
            } else {
                FaForward.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 68, 68));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've done the following steps:

1. After an initial load both `CanGoForward` and `CanGoBack` return `false` which is correct, because there is only entry in the history.
2. If I'm going to click a link in the browser the method will be called again. This time `CanGoForward` and `CanGoBack` again both return `false` which confuses me a little because a new page was loaded.
3. If I'm then clicking the Button `BtnBack` the browser navigates back to the first page and the method will be called. Now `CanGoBack` is `true` and `CanGoForward` is `false`, which seems to be the correct values for the second step.

Because there are always the values from the step before available, I assume that the event is risen/the method is called before the new history entry was added. While debugging my code the method will be called before the new page is rendered to the browser, which confirms my assumption.

So the question is, if there is an alternative event which is called after successfully loading a page in the browser? I wasn't able to find an appropriated method with intellisense or in the documentation.

Comment: Likely https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2624/back-and-forward-buttons-are-not-enabled

Comment: Will be included in version `73`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2696 for details of the release.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your effort. Keep up the good work!